# Material-UI Slider-range doesn't display floating numbers in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, slider

For my React app I used Slider-range component from material-ui.
The TS example watch [here](https://material-ui.com/ru/components/slider/#InputSlider.tsx). Here is my code:

```
const [zNumber, setZNumber] = React.useState<number | string | Array<number | string>>(0.9000);
const handleZNumberChange = (event: any, newValue: number | number[]) => {
    setZNumber(newValue);
  };
const handleZNumberInputChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setZNumber(event.target.value === '' ? '' : Number(event.target.value));
  };
const handleBlur = () => {
    if (zNumber < 0.9000) {
        setZNumber(0.9000);
    } else if (zNumber > 1.0000) {
        setZNumber(1.0000);
    }
  };
<Input 
        className='input'
            value={zNumber}
            onChange={handleZNumberInputChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            inputProps={{
              step: 0.0001,
              min: 0.9000,
              max: 1.0000,
              type: 'number',
              'aria-labelledby': 'input-slider',
            }}
          />
        <Slider
        className='slider'
            value={typeof zNumber === 'number' ? zNumber : 0.9000}
            onChange={handleZNumberChange}
            aria-labelledby="input-slider"
          />
```

Previously with  integers it worked correctly, but with float it is still shortened to 0.9.
Also, I didn't find nothing about float numbers in material-ui docs. Does anybody know, what can I do with it ?

Comment: Material ui with small steps https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-kttsr?file=/demo.tsx.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to use missed values. But still, I need slider with input and opportunity for user to change the value manually with the help of arrows. Like here in example: https://material-ui.com/ru/components/slider/#InputSlider.tsx

Comment: You can create that easily https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-kttsr?file=/demo.tsx.